# NodeJS - How to deal with UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I am fairly new to Node JS and so I am struggling a bit.

I am trying to read files for google drive using their API, from my Node Js code.

I am having the following code

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

  var pageToken = null;
// Using the NPM module 'async'
async.doWhilst(function (callback) {
  drive.files.list({
    q: "mimeType='image/jpeg'",
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
    spaces: 'drive',
    pageToken: pageToken
  }, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
      console.error(err);
      callback(err)
    } else {
      res.files.forEach(function (file) {
        console.log('Found file: ', file.name, file.id);
      });
      pageToken = res.nextPageToken;
      callback();
    }
  });
}, function () {
  return !!pageToken;
}, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    // All pages fetched
  }
})

  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

});
```

The above code is giving me the following error when i send the get request

```
(node:13884) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at E:\nodejs\newcelebapi\routes\index.js:49:17
    at E:\nodejs\newcelebapi\node_modules\googleapis-common\build\src\apirequest.js:43:53
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:13884) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13884) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The issue is in the following line

```
  res.files.forEach(function (file) {
```

I've tried everything I could and gave up understanding the problem.

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: JS moved on since that `async` package was written, and it has had support for [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and native [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) for quite a while now - I would strongly recommend not using that package unless you know JS well enough to be able to explain why native async/await or promises aren't good enough (which it feels is safe to say is not the case right now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this example in the doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs#step_3_set_up_the_sample), you want to be using:

```
res.data.files.forEach(...)
```

not:

```
res.files.forEach(...)
```

And, it looks like as soon as you get by that problem, you will have another problem because you are calling `res.render()` in the wrong place.  And, when you fix that, you will have an issue with redefining `res` in your Google callback which will hide the higher level `res` that you need for `res.render()`.

I would strongly recommend that you not use the `async` library here.  It doesn't seem like it's needed here and it just complicates things.  And, if you did need help doing coordination of asynchronous operations, promises is the modern way to do so.

You don't show what you're trying to do with the resulting files (other than logging them), but here's a simple implementation that does that:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  var pageToken = null;
  drive.files.list({
    q: "mimeType='image/jpeg'",
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
    spaces: 'drive',
    pageToken: pageToken
  }).then(response => {
      let files = response.data.files;
      files.forEach(file => console.log('Found file: ', file.name, file.id))
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
  }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
  });
});
```

Note, that I named the parameter from `drive.files.list()` to be named `response` instead of `res` so I can access both `res` from the `router.get()` callback and `response` from the `drive.files.list()` callback.  You gave them both the same name `res` which means you can't access the `router.get()` parameter of the same name.

Comment: Great! It has worked. I think I need to brush up my knowledge on Node Js to understand the last point. But, I see what you mean.

I upvoted the answer and I guess I am too new to do that, but it is recorded though!

Here is the message I got "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @ThikkaReya - Since you are new, you don't yet have enough reputation to upvote, but since you asked the question, you can "accept" the answer that best answered you question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will both indicate to the community that your question has been answered and will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.